# Using multiple ViewHolders with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

*(Tho i am working with Xamarin(C#), the codes or the structure should seem identical to Java.)*

So, in an `Activity`, i have a `ViewPager` and a `TabLayout`. Inside the `ViewPager`, there's a `Fragment`, which contains a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`.

I have two different layouts and i want to display them in the `RecyclerView`. After doing some research, this is what i ended up with :

***Created two ViewHolder(s)***

```
public class PostRegularViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
  public ImageView userImg { get; set; }
  public TextView userFullName { get; set; }

  public PostRegularViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
  {
   userImg = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.feed_user_image);
   userFullName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.username);
  }
}

public class CreatePostViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
  public ImageView userImg { get; set; }
  public TextView userFirstName { get; set; }
  public CreatePostViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
  {
   userImg = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.topBar_user_image);
   userFirstName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.user_headerbar_title);
  }
}
```

***Inside the Adapter, i have:***

```
public override int ItemCount
{
 get
 {
   if (postCollection != null)
   {
     return postCollection.Count;
   }
   return 1; //Couldn't figure out what to return, so returned 1.
  }
}

public PostRegularAdapter(List<PostRegular> postList = null, string userFirstName = null)
{
 if (postList != null)
 {
  postCollection = postList;
 }
 UserFirstName = userFirstName;
}

public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
 if (postCollection == null)
 {
  RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = new CreatePostViewHolder(LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customview_user_writepostbar, parent, false));
  return vh;
 }

 else
 {
  RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh2 = new PostRegularViewHolder(LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customview_postregular, parent, false));
  return vh2;
  }
}
```

***Inside my Fragment, i have:***

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  mainView = ///Inflated the mainview
  var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Context, LinearLayoutManager.Vertical, false);;
  recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
  recyclerView.SetAdapter(postRegularAdapter);

  postRegularAdapter = new PostRegularAdapter(userFirstName: "Aousaf");         
  recyclerView.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
  return mainView;
 }
```

Here, in the `OnCreateView` method of the `Fragment`, i add the first view to the `RecyclerView`. To add the other view, i have this method inside the fragment :

```
public void PopulateWithPosts()
{
  List<PostRegular> posts = new List<PostRegular>();
  posts.Add(new PostRegular() { //passing the properties here });
  postRegularAdapter.postCollection = posts;
  postRegularAdapter.NotifyItemInserted(posts.Count - 1);
  postRegularAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

I call the `PopulateWithPosts` method from my activity, inside the `OnTabSelected` event of the `TabLayout`.

The problem here is that, the `OnCreateViewHolder` is not being called when i call the `PopulateWithPosts` method, or to narrow down, when i call the `NotifyDataSetChanged` method. What i can see using the debugger is that, `OnCreateViewHolder` is not called, rather, `OnBindViewHolder` is called.

***The `OnBindViewHolder` method***

```
 public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
 {
  if (postCollection == null)
  {
   CreatePostViewHolder vh2 = holder as CreatePostViewHolder;
   vh2.userFirstName.Text = UserFirstName + ", share something inspiring!";
  }

  else
  {
    PostRegularViewHolder vh = holder as PostRegularViewHolder;
    //Working with the viewHolder...
  }
```

According to the logic, the `else` block gets executed, however, as `OnCreateViewHolder` was not called this time, the `holder` remains `CreatePostViewHolder` aka the previous ViewHolder, which results in the cast failing, so i end up with `vh` being null.

I am a little puzzled here. Is there a way to call the `OnCreateViewHolder` when needed? Am i going in the right direction with adding multiple VIewHolders to a RecyclerView ? What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When RecyclerView has multiple ViewHolders, we usually override `GetItemViewType` method.

```
getItemViewType(int position)
```

This method's default implementation will always return 0, indicating that there is only 1 type of view. In your case, it is not so, and so you will need find a way to assert which row corresponds to which view type.

Besides,when we should notice the `viewType` parameter of following method:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

According to the view type, we'll need to inflate the correct layout resource and create our view holder accordingly. The RecyclerView will handle recycling different view types in a way which avoids clashing of different view types.

For example:
(assume you can match your viewholders with your object's field `Type`)

```
private  const int LAYOUT_ONE = 0;
private  const int LAYOUT_TWO = 1;
```

method `GetItemViewType`

```
public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (items[position].Type == 0)
            return LAYOUT_ONE;
        else
            return LAYOUT_TWO;
    }
```

method `OnCreateViewHolder`

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = null;
        switch (viewType)
        {
            case LAYOUT_ONE:
                view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customview_user_writepostbar, parent, false);
                return new CreatePostViewHolder(view);

            case LAYOUT_TWO:
                view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customview_postregular, parent, false);
                return new PostRegularViewHolder(view);

        }
    }
```

method `OnBindViewHolder`

```
public override void 
        OnBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        int type = GetItemViewType(position);

        switch (type)
        {
            case LAYOUT_ONE:
                CreatePostViewHolder vh2 = holder as CreatePostViewHolder;
                vh2.userFirstName.Text = UserFirstName + ", share something inspiring!";
                break;
            case LAYOUT_TWO:
                PostRegularViewHolder vh = holder as PostRegularViewHolder;
                // other code
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tho i applied the solution before you posted the answer, but still deserve an upvote :)

Comment: Congrats, happy coding  :)